System sounds (beep, error, etc) are not working
Audio is working and I can play any music file. The sound of Windows notifications also works without an issue. However, traditional system sounds like the one you get with an error message, the one you hear when you try to click on a blocked window, etc., are not working for some reason. What's strange is that when I go to Sounds (under Themes settings), select any sound, and click "Test", all the sounds work just fine:

Things I tried:

Ensure sounds are not set to "None".
Ensure that "System Sounds" volume (under Volume Mixer) is not muted.
Restart Window Audio service and restart PC.
Update audio drivers.
Switch between speaker, headphones, bluetooth headphones, etc.
Device Manger > Show Hidden Devices: couldn't find "Non-Plug and Play Drivers".
Select different sounds in the dialog shown above.
Revert to default windows theme.
sfc /scannow

What am I missing? I really want to avoid having to reset the entire system or reinstall Windows if possible.

I found the problem. In my case, it was disabled in Windows Registry.
To fix the problem:

Open the Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound.
Change the value of "Beep" from "no" to "yes".
Restart the computer.


Most likely, Windows has been set to Presentation Mode, where "all the system notifications are turned off temporarily."
To turn Presentation Mode off (or on),

Press Windows and type presenta.

Select PresentationSettings.exe.


Uncheck (or check) I am currently giving a presentation.



I've never used that before and when I searched for PresentationSettings.exe and tried to open it, it said "Presentation Settings are available only on mobile PCs". Also, probably worth mentioning that I do get the sound of Windows notifications; just not the "legacy" system sounds like the beep sound, sound of error messages, etc.
